# Style for 2 line header

Tags: css, html-table, tableheader

i have a html table with two lines as header. I use the second row for a filter drop down. so it is empty in the table itself.

```html
    <table class="tg wrap stripe" id="tableData">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="header-left">Name</th>
                <th class="header-left">Position</th>
                <th class="header-left">Office</th>
                <th class="header-center">Age</th>
                <th class="header-center">Start date</th>
                <th class="header-right">Salary</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="header-left"></th>
                <th class="header-left"></th>
                <th class="header-left"></th>
                <th class="header-center"></th>
                <th class="header-center"></th>
                <th class="header-right"></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr> ... </tr>
            ...
```

Now I wanna show only the inner vertical borders and a bottom border for the header. Therefore I use this:

```
    .tg tr  td:first-child, th:first-child{
            border-left: none;
        }
    .tg tr  td:last-child, th:last-child{
            border-right: none;
        }
    .tg tr td, th {
            border-right: none;
            border-top: none;
            border-bottom: none;
        }
```

Border width is set to `1px` and `border-collapse:collapse` is also set.
But somehow I can draw a bottom line below the header (only below the second header line).
i already tried:

```
    .tg tr thead:last-child{
            border-bottom: 1px;
            }
```

and

```
    .tg tr th:last-child{
            border-bottom: 1px;
            }
```

without success.

```css
.tg tr td:first-child, th:first-child{
  border-left: none;
}
.tg tr td:last-child, th:last-child{
  border-right: none;
}
.tg tr td, th {
  border-right: none;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: none;
}

.tg tr thead:last-child{
  border-bottom: 1px;
}
.tg tr th:last-child{
  border-bottom: 1px;
}
```

```html
<table class="tg wrap stripe" id="tableData">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="header-left">Name</th>
      <th class="header-left">Position</th>
      <th class="header-left">Office</th>
      <th class="header-center">Age</th>
      <th class="header-center">Start date</th>
      <th class="header-right">Salary</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="header-left"></th>
      <th class="header-left"></th>
      <th class="header-left"></th>
      <th class="header-center"></th>
      <th class="header-center"></th>
      <th class="header-right"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr> ... </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Who can help me out?

Regards

Comment: Can you please show a proper [mre] of the issue, instead of these snippets.

Comment: This `.tg tr thead:last-child{ border-bottom: 1px; }` wont work as you try to set `tr` before `thead`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are having several lack:

- You must add border to `th` not the `tr`
- You must add the type of line you want and the color

You tried wrong css path here:

```css
.tg tr thead:last-child{
   border-bottom: 1px;
}
```

As `tr` is place before `thead` nothing will happen and `solid` or `color` which is the problem of your second try.

So you will have something like:

```css
.tg thead tr:last-child th{
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

After that if you want to remove the space between the border just set:

```css
table{
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

### DEMO

```css
.tg tr td:first-child, th:first-child{
  border-left: none;
}
.tg tr td:last-child, th:last-child{
  border-right: none;
}
.tg tr td, th {
  border-right: none;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: none;
}

.tg thead tr:last-child th{
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table class="tg wrap stripe" id="tableData">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="header-left">Name</th>
      <th class="header-left">Position</th>
      <th class="header-left">Office</th>
      <th class="header-center">Age</th>
      <th class="header-center">Start date</th>
      <th class="header-right">Salary</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="header-left"></th>
      <th class="header-left"></th>
      <th class="header-left"></th>
      <th class="header-center"></th>
      <th class="header-center"></th>
      <th class="header-right"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr> ... </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```